# Execute Loaded Lua files in a certain scope

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I'm using Lua as a configuration format for a project mine. Let's suppose I have the following contrived example, we'll call `conf.lua`:

```
title = "Lorem Ipsum"
author = "John Doe"
date = "01 January 2000"
```

Now, trivially, I can of course load this file like so:

```
dofile("conf.lua")
```

However, the problem with this is that these definitions are set in the global namespace, which I do not want. Furthermore, it makes it difficult to access the different variables as a whole (e.g loop over the set of configuration variables). One solution would be to rewrite `conf.lua` like so:

```
local conf = {
    title = "Lorem Ipsum",
    author = "John Doe",
    date = "01 January 2000"
}

return conf
```

and in turn, load `conf.lua` with the following code:

```
local configuration = dofile("conf.lua")
```

However, this is non-ideal for I think obvious reasons. It requires my users to keep track of commas, to have to write `local`, to have to remember to return the table at the end. What would be nice is if there were some way to cause `conf.lua` to execute with a custom scope of some sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using [`dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-dofile), simply use [`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-loadfile).

[`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-loadfile) allows you to specify the [*environment*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2) the loaded chunk will be executed in. Setting this as an empty table allows *upvalues* to be placed in that table.

```
local function load_conf ()
    local env = {}

    local chunk, err = loadfile('conf.lua', 'bt', env)

    if not err then
        chunk()
    end

    return env, err
end
```

---

```
local conf, conf_err = load_conf()

print(conf_err)
print(conf.title, conf.author, conf.date)
```

[`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-loadfile) uses similar rules as [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load), except that it loads a chunk from a file, or `stdin`, instead of from a string or string building function.

---

Note that [`setfenv`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv) is required for backwards compatibility with [Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/). You'd use the following (or something like it) before executing your loaded chunk.

```
if setfenv then
    setfenv(chunk, env)
end
```

See [§8.1 – Changes in the Language](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.1) of the [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html).

---

Finally, consider running your chunks in *protected mode*, using [`pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pcall), so that a config file doesn't crash your main program.